# Is connection order maintained when multiple client sockets attempt to connect at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, serversocket

The overall question is this:

> Can the server sockets accept multiple connections at the same time? (Multiple clients sockets asking to connect at the same time before the server id done responding to the other request), Would the other clients block? Is the order maintained?

My answer so far is yes, as long as a new thread is created for each new connection, however I don't how this effects the connection order, my first thought is that no, the order would not be maintained, but I cannot find any confirmation of this.

If this question is already answered somewhere I apologize, but I can't seem to find anything definitive.

Comment: 'Same time' and 'order' are mutually contradictory, and 'order' isn't well-defined. Order of arrival of the initial SYN? Of the final ACK? Of the beginning of the request data? Of the end of the request data? And are you aware of the existence and function of the backlog queue?

Comment: @user207421 I apologize for the vagueness of the question, but unfortunately that's a copy-paste of the question I've been given. To answer your second question, no I am not familiar.

Comment: Well my answer would consist at of my first seven words above, and a request for clarification of the other issues I raised. I would also add that on a network there is no such thing as 'same time'. But if you're not aware of the backlog queue you haven't been taught enough, or have missed too many classes :-), to be able to answer the question accurately. Anyway what you need to do here is post *your* answer for comment, confirmation, or rebuttal.